# I want to search through the field in the array in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

The documents are stored in the form below in Elastic Research index.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "value1": "test1",
            "value2": "test2"
        },
        {
            "value1": "test3",
            "value2": "test4"
        },
        {
            "value1": "test5",
            "value2": "test6"
        }
    ]
}
```

Among the array values in the data field,
If any of the conditions are correct, I would like to return the document

The documents shall be returned under the following conditions.

```
"value1": "test3" and "value2": "test4"
```

However, documents should not be returned under the following conditions.

```
"value1": "test3" and "value2": "test7"
```

In this case, how should I make the query condition?

Comment: What if both the conditions you mentioned evaluated to true. Do you want to return the doc? Can you please bring clarity to the question?

Comment: @myskbj did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a working example with index mapping, search query, and search result.

Refer [nested field for array of objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) to get a detailed explanation.

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "data": {
        "type": "nested" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "data",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "data.value1": "test3"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "data.value2": "test4"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "stof",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.9616582,
                "_source": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "value1": "test1",
                            "value2": "test2"
                        },
                        {
                            "value1": "test3",
                            "value2": "test4"
                        },
                        {
                            "value1": "test5",
                            "value2": "test6"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Thank you that the answer was helpful.

Comment: @myskbj thanks for your reply :) It would be great if you can accept and upvote my answer as well :)